# Expression must have pointer to object type error in MPI send

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I got syntax error in `MPI send` command. I wanted to send some rows and respective columns with it. I have got error in this line `MPI_Send(&(array[ch_row][ch_col]), ch_size*col, MPI_INT, p, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD)` at `ch_col`. I can't understand why I and getting this error.

```
 int tot_processes;
        int process_id;
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &tot_processes);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_id);
        if (process_id == 0) {
            int row, col;
            cout << "Enter rows and columns: ";
            cin >> row >> col;
            int *array = new int[row*col];
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    array[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
            int ch_size = row / tot_processes;
            for (int p = 1; p < tot_processes; p++) {
                int ch_row = ch_size * (p - 1);
                int ch_col = ch_size * col;
                MPI_Send(&ch_size, 1, MPI_INT, p, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&(array[ch_row][ch_col]), ch_size*col, MPI_INT, p, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `array` is an `int *`, so `array[I][j]` is incorrect.

Comment: `int * array = new int[row*col]`; This is one dimensional array. You need to work with it using one dimension in all cases, like `array[i*row + j]` or something like this. Two dimensional array should be declared as `int**`. Or better, use std::vector.

Comment: thank you very much @AlexF it worked